# java callback function in case of an exception

Tags: java, lambda, interface, callback

I've to implement a callback mechanism in case of an exception.
suppose i hv a code to call like , which takes 3 parameters
inside a class called ServiceA

```
serviceA.functionA(String str1, String str2, Str3)
```

which is inside an i/o call or call to an other service
now if this call fails then i need to call an another similar function
which is in class called ServiceB

```
serviceB.functionB(String str1, String str2, Str3)..if there is an exception
```

which should execute functionB if there is any exception in FunctionA..or functionA return a code other than 2xx ..

what would be the way to implement in using interfaces in java 8.
is this could be implement using lambda and functional interfaces

the code i'm looking through java8 functional interface..should perform similar to the try catch block like this

```
try{
serviceA.functionA(String str1, String str2, Str3)
}
catch(Exception ex){
if(ex.errorCode != 200)
serviceB.functionB(String str1, String str2, Str3)
}
```

i search through some online contents ..but couldn't find any appropriate answer

Answer (score 0):

you could treate your logic about exception or != 200 inside functionA and throw your custom exception ( or manage this on specific return from functionA ), example on exception bellow:

create your exception

```java
 class MyExceptionGotInsideFunctionA extends RuntimeException {
        
 }
```

your can throw your new exception inside your functionA

```
    functionA(String str1, String str2, String Str3){

        try{
           var reponse = otherService();

           if( response == 200 )  throw new MyExceptionGotInsideFunctionA("response != 200");

        }catch(  Exception e ){
            throw new MyExceptionGotInsideFunctionA(e.getMessage());
        }

    }
```

treaing yout thrown exception

```
try{
    serviceA.functionA(String str1, String str2, Str3) // will try run
}catch(MyExceptionGotInsideFunctionA ex){
   serviceB.functionB(String str1, String str2, Str3)
}
```

if you work with a simple boolean return from functionA to call funcionB will be cleanner and better.

```java
boolean functionA(String str1, String str2, String Str3){

        try{
           var reponse = otherService();

           return response != 200;

        }catch(  Exception e ){
            return false;
        }

    }
```

Comment: Hi .. thanks for you comment .. i'm looking for a way to implement this try catch logic through callback functions .with java 8 ..function interface

Answer (score 0):

You can try to take a look at the try-monads from [VAVR](https://github.com/vavr-io/vavr) or [Cyclops](https://github.com/aol/cyclops).
Both should be able to do what you want. Something like this should be possible:

```
private void handleError(BusinessException ex) {
    if(ex.getCode() == 200) {
         serviceB.functionB(str1, str2, str3);
    }
}

private void execute() {
    Try.runWithCatch(serviceA.functionA(str1, str2, str3)).onFail(this::handleError);
}
```

The problem would be how to pass the values of the str1/str2/str3 to the handling function.

Edit: Extending the Cyclops try seems for me the best bet doing something like this.

```
public class MyTry<T,X> extends Try<T,X> {    
    public Try<T,X> onFail(Predicate<X> predicate, Consumer<X> consumer)
         // filter according to to predicate
         // execute consumer
    }
}
```

And then you could do something like this:

```
private void execute() {
    Try.runWithCatch(serviceA.functionA(str1, str2,str3)).onFail(ex -> ex.getCode() == 200, ex -> serviceB.functionB(str1, str2, str3));
}
```

Comment: Hi ..thanks for your comment .. while this looks good .. i may not be able to include any library for this task ... wanted to use existing features of java

Comment: Then try to read up the try monad pattern and implement it yourself. A simple implementation(not supporting all uses cases, only the one you need) should not really be a lot of code. You can take a look at https://github.com/jasongoodwin/better-java-monads/blob/master/src/main/java/com/jasongoodwin/monads/Try.java and use it as an inspiration and adapt the code to your needs.